# Delete all bookmarks from Google Chrome macOS app in one go

Tags: macos, google-chrome

How can I delete all the bookmarks in Google Chrome macOS app with one delete command?

Most solutions on the Web say to delete them one at a time. I have hundreds I want to clear. I imagine there is a file somewhere that contains them. Where can I find and delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily delete all the bookmarks in Google Chrome in one go.

1. Open Bookmark manager by going to Bookmarks → Bookmark Manager or by using keyboard short <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.
2. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all bookmarks and folders.

[image]

3. Press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to delete all the bookmarks in one go.

[image]

Do note that Google Chrome doesn't ask for confirmation before deleting the bookmarks. They are gone as soon as you press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. However, you can undo the delete operation by clicking on the **Undo** button shown in the bottom left for a few seconds, immediately after the operation is performed.

Comment: Yes. I just checked and confirmed that this is the best answer. Then I shamefacedly deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a reasonable solution to this problem.

1. Go to the Bookmark Manager in Chrome (Bookmarks -> Bookmark Manager).
2. Create a folder named "Begone".
3. Drag all folders and bookmarks into Begone.
4. Delete Begone with "..." menu on the right of the folder entry.

Answer (score 0):

The file you're looking for can be found by <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in Finder and typing:

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks`.

Comment: Turns out the problem there was that it got repopulated by the Google cloud.